# including boost source files in project using eclipse

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost libraries in an application which is targeted for multiple platforms including android.

unfortunately boost libraries are not included in android so i am trying to include the boost source files in project and compile them but i am getting many errors when i am trying to do that mostly unresolved symbols in many files

i have created the project as a shared library using eclipse ide and os is ubuntu 11.10

please help and i am not really a nerd so easy to understand solution would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a folder called `local/include/` in your home folder. Then create a symbolic link from `/usr/include/boost` to there. Include `~/local/include` in the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable in your `Android.mk`. This will work for the header-only libraries in boost.

Comment: thank you very much,some where i read about bcp provided by boost any idea about it?actually i am trying to target my application for almost all available platforms of both desktop and mobiles so can you help me with this.

Comment: Why do you need to use bcp? Header-only libraries compile into your binaries. You don't have to distribute the libraries with the binaries. bcp is only useful if you want to share the source code with people along with the libraries that you use.

Comment: yes thats what i am trying to do ,distribute the boost source code with my code.

Comment: @ken just use `bcp --boost=/usr/include --scan yoursourcefile.cpp ./the_folder_where_you_want_the_boost_headers`